# C++ how to to convert integers and longs to char arrays

Tags: c++, c, kernel

So how do I convert long or int into a c style char array? I can't use any outside libraries because I'm developing my own kernel.

Comment: Can you use SO search?

Comment: Do you mean convert a number into a human-readable string representation?

Comment: Converted to bit-octets, base-10 digits, ascii?

Comment: Its intented to convert the number to base ten. Intented to convert the number digit by digit into chars and put them to array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Converted to decimal ascii string (not nul-terminated, buffer 'large enough') :

```
size_t ultoa (char *buf, unsigned long u)
{
    char *bptr = buf, *df, *dr;

    do *bptr = ('0') + (char) (u % 10);
    while ((u /= 10) != 0);

    for (df = buf, dr = bptr - 1; df < dr; )
    {
        char di = *df, dj = *dr;
        *df++ = dj, *dr-- = di; // (exchange)
    }

    return ((size_t) (bptr - buf)); // (digits)
}
```